# MYSQL / PHP /SuiteCRM to automatically route Inbound email to lead in SuiteCRM

Tags: php, mysql, sugarcrm, suitecrm

We are looking at deploying SuiteCRM Company wide.  We have a development environment which we are testing all the required features and modules that we will required, and at the same time demoing to the management teams what the system will eventually look like.

We have a problem in that at current we have around 6 different websites/microsites that are hosted and designed by 6 different companies (all sadly managed by our marketing department, hence 6 companies!)

At current the contact form comes in to an email address (webenquires@) and then gets routed via our ancient mailserver.

We will be migrating to office 365 the same time as we roll out the new CRM.

I am looking for a solution to automatically create a lead from an inbound email in SuiteCRM.
Yes I am aware of doing it via campaigns and forms, however trying to get all 6 companies to make the correct changes at go live the same time will fail.  We struggle to get typo's corrected properly, so form changes 1st time just won't happen.

We also need to demo this system for a few weeks to various management teams, and would like to implement the form changes 1 site and company at a time allowing for problems. Our goal is to fully migrate and run with forms from Suite in 3-6 months, or sooner if no problems.

What I need is a temporary solution to do this via:

Either MySQL / inner Join
PHP coding
Or some kind of workflow

The correct inbound email address (webenquiries) is already configured and working in SuiteCRM.

https://community.sugarcrm.com/thread/25193

I tried the following inner join from the example above which is based on Sugar CE6.5 failed.  I modified it to work with SuiteCRM and it now generates a Lead, however its totally blank, and I am not sure how I could map the fields in the 2 files across to the correct fields in SuiteCRM?

```
 use test;
    SELECT emails_text.*
    FROM emails_text
    INNER JOIN emails ON emails.id = emails_text.email_id
    WHERE emails.mailbox_id IN ( '<9ecf0144-df77-b486-2a81-59e4cfa82f69>' )
    AND emails.name = 'New Lead'
```

Attached is 2 examples of the inbound emails that come through.

Answer (score 0):

you can check scheduler job function (function::pollMonitoredInboxes) which fetch emails. That contain code which is used for email fetching. track back code and you will find everything you want. Map any field from email to lead easily.

If you write your lead creation code in email fetching function(create and call custom helper method for lead creation) then you can achieve your desired results easily.